# How to pass values from server side to client side during callback in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback

I need to pass some values from server-side to client-side during callback. What I need to do is to show some alert window with values form server-side. During a postback is quite easy using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, but how to initialize a client javascript variable during a generic callback?

Comment: You can always use `HiddenField`

Comment: You can set js variable value using same thing `RegisterStartupScript` and that js variable should be global variable, so that other JS function can use them.

Comment: Can you better explain HiddenField tecnique?